# D3 radarchart does not show properly in Safari

Tags: javascript, d3.js, safari, typo3

So I have a weird bug. In my development environment I cannot create background circles in safari for my radarchart if the following is added to my code. The g elements are in the inspector. They just do now visually show. It works perfect for FF and Chrome:

```
    .style("filter", "url(#glow)");
```

Out of

```
//Draw the background circles
axisgrid
    .selectAll(".levels")
    .data(d3
        .range(1, cfg.levels + 1)
        .reverse())
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .transition()
    .duration(200)
    .attr("class", "gridcircle")
    .attr("r", function (d, i) {
        return radius / cfg.levels * d;
    })
    .style("fill", "#CDCDCD")
    .style("stroke", "#CDCDCD")
    .style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacitycircles)
    .style("filter", "url(#glow)");
```

However it works perfect in my codepen example https://codepen.io/Nickka87/pen/pdzqOZ

on both safari and chrome.

So it must be something in my setup. The SVG elements are inside "html" so xmlns should not be needed. Or what?

In my typo3 setup run in Safari this only replicates as [image]

[image]

Comment: The big question is: Where do you define these? Maybe the fluid parser skip some of your code.

Comment: Hi Rene, the chart(s) are defined in seperate js files in the extension used. Theyre loaded after the librarys used (jquery, d3 etc). Fluid should not interfere here, but Im unsure. Still it works as intended in chrome and ff :/

Comment: Maybe it is some bug with other code or elements in safari. in my opinion safari is the new internet explorer ;)

Comment: Yeah, I dont disagree with that.. My only idea is that i can see xmlns for svg is defined somewhere else, in a div outside of the scope of the chart, but still in the same html ofcourse... Could this interfere?

Comment: Could be of course... For me as windows developer it is always hard to understand and resolve bugs on Safari...